# Excel- Getting values from random last date of a given month

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am working on data of daily market capitalization of stocks of around 400 companies. Each company's data ranges from 2000 to 2016. However, I want to pick market capitalization on the last date of june and on the last date of december. Further, these last dates does not always mean end of the month date. For example; for December, one company had last market capitalization available on 14th of December.

To summarize my problem again, I want to pick the last "available" market capitalization for the month of june and the last available market capitalization for the month of Dec from the year 2000 to 2016.

Kindly help me out, or give me a direction to approach this problem. As last date of available value does not mean end of the month value, I guess I can not use end of the month formula. The lookup function also does not look feasable.

Again I appreciate any suggestion you can offer. Thank You in advance.

Sample Data

```
Date   - Closing - Market Capitalization  
2-Jan  - 23.5    - 177,282,000    
1-Jan  - 22      - 177,282,000    
31-Dec - 33      - 177,282,000    
30-Dec - 33      - 177,282,000    
4-Jul  - 31      - 120,960,000  
2-Jul  - 31.1    - 113,400,000  
1-Jul  - 31      - 113,400,000  
28-Jun - 30      - 113,400,000  
27-Jun - 30      - 113,400,000  
26-Jun - 30.1    - 113,400,000
```

[image: Data picture]

Comment: Fo further background of the data. I first arrange the data using vlookup. So the dates that do not have market capitalization have "#N.A" value. So what I am trying is that I "also" get last june market capitalization and last december market capitalization on my work sheet when I align data using VLOOKUP.

Comment: looking at your data will go a long way in figuring out what formulas you are going to need.  provide a small sample of data as text in your question so people can copy and paste it and you will get a lot more help

Comment: As it currently stands, we do not know if you data is laid out horizontally, vertically or just plain scattered.  We do not know if your dates are an excel date formatted to display as a date or a string of the date.  We do not know what your headers are if any.  etc.

Comment: The data is aligned vertically. Has three columns with headers "date", "closing price of stocks" and "market capitalization". Date is excel formatted mm-dd-yyyy.

Comment: please edit your question and include the small sample table showing what you just said in comments.  do not worry too much about alignment, we can help edit it and make it look pretty afterwards

Comment: Done sir, I hope I am clear enough now

Comment: Much better, and very clear.  Still have one question though...how do you know what company you are dealing with?  I assume the data you are showing is for one company?  I dont see any company identifier column.  Is each table its own company?

Comment: Yes sir, each company's data is in a seperate file.

Comment: Might want to tack on the years to the dates in your question.  When people ansering bring it to their own worksheets, they currently cant tell what year each date belongs to.  You questions states that they could be anywhere from 2000-2016.  That brings up a good question, is it safe to assume the dates will be sorted in ascending order?

Comment: Sorry Sir, the dates are actually in descending order.

Comment: as long as they are sorted it makes it easier to work with then if they ae scrambled.

Comment: Yes sir. They are sorted in descending order. Data goes in a sequence. However the dates are skipped when data for that date is not available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this array formula:

```
=INDEX($C$2:$C$11,MATCH(TRUE,(MIN(IF($A$2:$A$11<=EOMONTH(E6,0),EOMONTH(E6,0)-$A$2:$A$11))=IF($A$2:$A$11<=EOMONTH(E6,0),EOMONTH(E6,0)-$A$2:$A$11)),0))
```

being an array formula it must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter.  If done correctly then excel will put `{}` around the formula.

[image]

---

If you were able to sort the dates in ascending order then you can use this non array formula:

```
=INDEX($C$2:$C$11,MATCH(EOMONTH(E6,0),$A$2:$A$11,1))
```

[image]

Comment: Sure now that I got all the questions sorted out 8P hehehe

Comment: Apparently EOMONTH does not work in an array.aggregate.  `=INDEX($C$2:$C$11,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($A$2:$A$11)/(EOMONTH($A$2:$A$11,0)=E2),1))`

Comment: Still cannot get the values. I guess I am not doing it properly.

Comment: @SubhanAhmad do you see {} around your formula after you enter it in the formula bar?  you cannot add those {} manually

Comment: If I convert the data into ascending order, will that help? You said that array formula wont be needed then.

Comment: actually there are 4019 values. For example dates (A3:A4027).

Comment: If you please explain this formula to me a bit so that I can understand its working. This might help me in adjusting the formula to my needs.

Comment: 4019 may be the excel date as an integer.  Format your cell to display date

Comment: Yes Sir, I got it working. Thank You very very much.. !!

Comment: Thanks @ForwardEd for handling the question, I was in the kitchen cooking dinner.

Comment: @ScottCraner I am doing finger cooking tonight...ordering pizza online!

Comment: Scott, does your solution have the same caveat as mine and that it will only look in the month of june or the month of December, or will it also look at say march if it happened to be the last entry?

Comment: @ForwardEd It will find the closest date that is not greater than the end of the month in december or june.  It can be any date prior whether in that month or not.

Answer (score 1):

Potential solution.  Has a minor caveat to it that I will get to at the end.

Lets day in column E we generate a list of target dates we want to search for.  They will be the end dates of the month of june and December.  Each row will advance the previous date by 6 months.

In E2 we put the seeder date in at:

```
=EOMONTH(DATE(2000,6,1),0)
```

In E3 we put our list generator in as follows and copy down as far as we need:

```
=EOMONTH(E2,6)
```

In G2 we use the following formula and copy down as far as we need:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($C$2:$C$11,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($A$2:$A$11)/((MONTH($A$2:$A$11)=MONTH(E2))*(YEAR($A$2:$A$11)=YEAR(E2))),1)-1),"NOT FOUND")
```

The caveat is the market capitalization has to occur in at least the month of June or December.  Outside of those months will not be looked at.

If you want to display the date that the number you pulled corresponds to since its not actually the last day of the month, you could place that date in column F with:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$11,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($A$2:$A$11)/((MONTH($A$2:$A$11)=MONTH(E2))*(YEAR($A$2:$A$11)=YEAR(E2))),1)-1),"NOT FOUND")
```

Proof of Concept

[image: Proof of Concept]